# How to add div's inside a div dynamically until the width and height of parent div is full/completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tile

**Background:** I am making a web-page where User will enter the tile Width & Height and Floor Width & Height.
The Floor Width & Height is used to calculate the area of Floor.
The Tile input is in INCHES & the Floor Input is in FEET.

**Technical Info:** I have set 1 foot equals to 60 pixels & 1 inch equals to 5 pixels for calculations.

**Where Am I Now ?** 
Right now I am stuck in drawing all the tiles *(child div's)* in the area *(parent div)*. For now I am using simple `for` loop for making the tiles *(div's)*.

For Now Output is Something Like this...

[image]

**What I Want ?** Well I am trying to make a functionality that when user clicks the Calculate Button, he/she see's the design of the floor. *I will be coloring & adding patterns later on.*

The output should be like this *(Beg me your pardon, if the borders are not align, this was made with Windows Paint)* :

[image]

**Code:**

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnCalculate").click(function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault();

                $("#area").empty();

                const foot = 60, inch = 5;

                let tileW = parseFloat($("#tileWidth").val());
                let tileH = parseFloat($("#tileHeight").val());

                let areaW = parseFloat($("#areaWidth").val());
                let areaH = parseFloat($("#areaHeight").val());
                
                $("#area").css("height", (foot * areaH));
                $("#area").css("width", (foot * areaW));


                for (let r = 0; r<10  ; r++) {
                    // const element = array[r];
                    $("#area").append("<div id='tile_"+r+"' style='width:"+((inch * tileW))+"px; height:"+((inch * tileH))+"px;' class='border_color'> </div>");
                    
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
#area {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
        }
        .border_color{
            /* border: 1px solid black; */
            outline: 1px solid; /* use instead of border */
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Tile Width (inches): </p><input type="numbers" id ="tileWidth" placeholder="Tile Width" value="6">
    <p>Tile Height (inches): </p><input type="numbers" id ="tileHeight" placeholder="Tile Height" value="4">
    <br>
    <p>Area Width (foot): </p><input type="numbers" id ="areaWidth" placeholder="Area Width" value="11.5">
    <p>Area Height (foot): </p><input type="numbers" id ="areaHeight" placeholder="Area Height" value="6.5">
    <button id="btnCalculate" >Calculate</button>
        
    

    <div id="area">

    </div>
```

External Link of Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/22gLkguL/

I Have tried, to archive all of this but failed..!
Would someone please help me OR guide me in right path...?

Comment: you mean to see all `div`  vertical in the end of `erea`(foot)???

Comment: @לבנימלכה I added more details, for how the output should be..!

Comment: so, u want the inner divs to fill the box and not go out of box?

Comment: Yes @GautamNaik , This is exactly what I want !

Comment: Have u thought of using canvas?

Comment: No @GautamNaik , actually I didn't know how to use canvas ! I new to all this stuff !

Comment: @Zakawat maybe you can do it by create table... If you think so tell me I will help you

Comment: okay @לבנימלכה let's give it a shot with table !
I was working with div's because I thought it is better approach..!
Actually I don't know about this fonrtend stuff, I am Backend guy !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `display: flex` and `flex-wrap: wrap`

```
#area {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

and calculate the numbers of the `div`s that each side (width or height) can be filled the most.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnCalculate").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#area").empty();

    const foot = 60,
      inch = 5;

    let tileW = parseFloat($("#tileWidth").val());
    let tileH = parseFloat($("#tileHeight").val());

    let areaW = parseFloat($("#areaWidth").val());
    let areaH = parseFloat($("#areaHeight").val());
    
    var areaHeight = (foot * areaH)
    var areaWidth = (foot * areaW)
    var divHeight = (inch * tileH)
    var divWidth = (inch * tileW)
    
    $("#area").css("height", areaHeight);
    $("#area").css("width", areaWidth);

    var nums = Math.floor(areaWidth/divWidth) * Math.floor(areaHeight/divHeight)

    for (let r = 0; r < nums; r++) {
      var $div = $('<div>', {
        id: 'tile_' + r,
        class: 'border_color',
        height: divHeight,
        width: divWidth,
      })
      $("#area").append($div);

    }
  });
});
```

```css
#area {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

.border_color {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Tile Width (inches): </p><input type="numbers" id="tileWidth" placeholder="Tile Width" value="6">
<p>Tile Height (inches): </p><input type="numbers" id="tileHeight" placeholder="Tile Height" value="4">
<br>
<p>Area Width (foot): </p><input type="numbers" id="areaWidth" placeholder="Area Width" value="11.5">
<p>Area Height (foot): </p><input type="numbers" id="areaHeight" placeholder="Area Height" value="6.5">
<button id="btnCalculate">Calculate</button>



<div id="area">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

use `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap` for area element.

and calculate the number of Tiles as ---

> (areaWidthInPixels/tileWidthinPixels) *
>   (areaHeightInPixels/tileHeightinPixels)

```js
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnCalculate").click(function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault();

                $("#area").empty();

                const foot = 60, inch = 5;

                let tileW = parseFloat($("#tileWidth").val());
                let tileH = parseFloat($("#tileHeight").val());

                let areaW = parseFloat($("#areaWidth").val());
                let areaH = parseFloat($("#areaHeight").val());
                
                $("#area").css("height", (foot * areaH));
                $("#area").css("width", (foot * areaW));
                
                let noOfTiles = Math.floor( ((foot * areaW)/(inch * tileW)) )* Math.floor( ((foot * areaH)/(inch * tileH)) );
        
                alert("noOf TIles :: " + noOfTiles);
                
                for (let r = 1; r <= noOfTiles  ; r++) {
                    // const element = array[r];
                    var bgColor = r % 2 == 0 ? "red" : "green";
                    $("#area").append("<div id='tile_"+r+"' style='width:"+((inch * tileW))+"px; height:"+((inch * tileH))+"px; background-color: " + bgColor + "'' class='border_color'> </div>");
                    
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
#area {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 25px;
            width: 25px;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .border_color{
            /* border: 1px solid black; */
            outline: 0px solid; /* use instead of border */
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Tile Width (inches): </p><input type="numbers" id ="tileWidth" placeholder="Tile Width" value="6">
    <p>Tile Height (inches): </p><input type="numbers" id ="tileHeight" placeholder="Tile Height" value="4">
    <br>
    <p>Area Width (foot): </p><input type="numbers" id ="areaWidth" placeholder="Area Width" value="11.5">
    <p>Area Height (foot): </p><input type="numbers" id ="areaHeight" placeholder="Area Height" value="6.5">
    <button id="btnCalculate" >Calculate</button>
        
    

    <div id="area">

    </div>
```

Comment: jsfiddle is added !